# Smart contract DB

Tags: solidity, contract-development, database

Is it a good practice to create a smart contract to serve as a DB table? 
For example, lets say that I have users that need to create `Operations`. 
My operations objects need to contain `id`, `description`, `date to start` and `date to finish`. Ideally I know I could store this in centralized DB. Although for my business requirements, if would be convenient to have this data completely open. I know my use case does not require Eth or any other token transfer, is this still a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do so. Although your Contract would have costs for Write and Update operations. I think AusIV answers your question in some way with [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/25419/57792)

Comment: Appreciate it! I didn't see that thread before.